# Convert complex txt to csv python script

Tags: python, database, csv, text, export-to-csv

I have a `.txt` file with this inside

```
Name: 321; 
Score:100; Used Time: 1:09:308;
GTime: 6/28/2024 10:04:18 PM;
Core Version : 21.0.0.0;
Software Version : 21.0.0.0;
AppID: 0S0; MapDispName: Future City; MapName:MapName MapName MapName;
Key:A0000-abcde-Q0000-F0000-00H00;  REG Date : 2/27/2021 1:16:34 PM; Expiry : 7/7/2024 12:00:00 AM
```

What I'm trying to do is convert that text into a `.csv` (table) using a python script.
There are 300 files and hundreds of lines in each file. We only need to transform the information in the first 7 lines into csv. All of these 300 files have the same format but with different values.

What I would want the `log.csv` file to show is:

```
Name,Sore,Time,Software Ver,Core Ver,AppID,Key,REG Date,Expiry,MapName
321,100,69.308s,21.0.0.0,21.0.0.0,0S0,A0000-abcde-Q0000-F0000-00H00,2/27/2021 1:16:34 PM,7/7/2024 12:00:00 AM,MapName MapName MapName
```

How can I do it with python? Thanks.

Comment: for exports to csv you can check out python's builtin CSV library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). For parsing the input file, you're gonna have to come up with some custom logic. You can have a look ar regular expressions, maybe they will be helpful (https://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: You need to manually `parse` the data. Such as: `name, line = line.split(':', 1)`, then `score, line = line.strip().split('\t')`

Comment: Is there just one entry in your txt file or are there multiple? If there are multiple, are they all 3 lines long? Is there a blank line separating entries?

Comment: There are 300 files and hundreds of lines in each file. We only need to transform the information in the first 8 lines into csv. All of these 300 files have the same format but with different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current example shows that all values appear to follow the same format i.e. `Key:Value;`

Use `glob.glob()` to iterate over all of your text filenames. You can use `islice()` to read in exactly 7 lines, then convert them into a single line. This can then be split on `;` to give you a list of key value pairs. These can then be further split on the `:` and `strip()` applied to remove any extra spaces.

Lastly make use of `itemgetter()` to extract only the elements you need from the resulting list.

```
from itertools import islice, chain
from operator import itemgetter
import csv
import glob
import os

get = itemgetter(1, 3, 5, 9, 11, 13, 19, 21, 23, 17)

with open('log.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow('Name,Sore,Time,Software Ver,Core Ver,AppID,Key,REG Date,Expiry,Filename'.split(','))

    for filename in glob.glob('*.txt', recursive=True):
        with open(filename) as f_input:
            data = ''.join(islice(f_input, 0, 7)).replace('\n', '').split(';')
            values = [v.strip() for v in chain.from_iterable(d.split(':', 1) for d in data)]
            csv_output.writerow([*get(values), os.path.basename(filename)])
```

For your example, this would give you `log.csv` containing:

```
Name,Sore,Time,Software Ver,Core Ver,AppID,Key,REG Date,Expiry,Filename
321,100,1:09:308,21.0.0.0,21.0.0.0,0S0,A0000-abcde-Q0000-F0000-00H00,2/27/2021 1:16:34 PM,7/7/2024 12:00:00 AM,MapName MapName MapName,file1.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin. The code works!!!
At the same time, if I could like to keep the txt file's name in one more column in the log.csv, what should I do? Many thanks

Comment: Yes, the filename can easily be added to the end (or prefixed) to each row, I've updated the script to show you how

Comment: Hi Martin. I have updated my question. Could you please advise what should I do, thanks.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66461035/convert-many-complex-txt-files-into-excel-xls-and-save-their-names-in-python-scr