# Convert many complex txt files into excel.xls and save their names in python script

Tags: python, excel, database, text, export-to-excel

I have many txt files with the standard format in the same folder:

```
Name: 321; 
Score:100; Used Time: 1:09:308;
GTime: 6/28/2024 10:04:18 PM;
Core Version : 21.0.0.0;
Software Version : 21.0.0.0;
AppID: 0S0; MapDispName: Future City; MapName:MapName123;
Key:A0000-abcde-Q0000-F0000-00H00;  REG Date : 2/27/2021 1:16:34 PM; Expiry : 7/7/2024 12:00:00 AM
```

I would like to convert those text files into an excle.xls (table) using a python script. At the same time, I would like to save text filenames as well.

```
Team ID, Result, Used Time,Software Ver, Core Ver, AppID, Key, REG Date, Expiry,MapName,TXTName
321,100,69.308s,21.0.0.0,21.0.0.0,0S0,A0000-abcde-Q0000-F0000-00H00,2/27/2021 1:16:34 PM,7/7/2024 12:00:00 AM,MapName123,TXTName1
```

Part of my code as below, but it's not working. **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'str'** in the penultimate line.

```
list_drr=[]
xls_name=None
for path, file_dir, files in os.walk(file_name_path):
    for file_name in files:
        list_drr.append(os.path.join(path, file_name))
    for dir in file_dir:
        list_drr.append(os.path.join(path, dir))#

excel_data= ExcelData(xls_name,"")
excel_datas= excel_data.readExcel()
print(excel_datas)
excel_header=['Team ID', 'Result', 'Used Time', 'Software Ver', 'Core Version', 'AppID', 'Key', 'REG Date', 'Expiry','MapName','TXTName']

file= WFile(excel_header)
for drr in list_drr:
    file_datas= getFileData(drr)
    file_datas=file_datas[:7]
    data_list=[]
    for  data in file_datas:
        lis= data.split(";")
        for li in lis:
            data_list.append(li)

    data_dic={}
    for data in data_list:
        pos= data.find(":")
        ddq=data[:pos].strip()
        data_dic[ddq]=data[pos+1:].strip()
    file.write((data_dic) + (os.path.basename(file_name)))
file.save("excel.xls")
```

Please advise what should I do, thanks.

**Updated wri_file.py as below.**

```
import xlwt

class WFile():
    def __init__(self,head_name):
        super().__init__()
        self.head_name=head_name
        self.index=0
        self. workbook =xlwt. Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
        self. worksheet =   self.workbook.add_sheet('Sheet1')
        self.line =len( self.head_name)

        for i in range( self.line):
            self.worksheet.write( self.index,i ,self.head_name[i])

        self.index+=1

    def write(self,d):
        for i in range( self.line):
            name=d.get(self.head_name[i])
            self.worksheet.write( self.index,i ,(name))
        self.index += 1

    def writes(self, d):
        for i in range(self.line):
            self.worksheet.write(self.index, i,d[i])
        self.index += 1

    def save(self,name):
        self.workbook.save(name)
```

Comment: Given the error, you probably need something like this: `file.write({**data_dic, 'TXTName': os.path.basename(file_name)})`. That will add the `TXTName` field to the dictionary being written to the file.

Comment: What is WFile? is it some sort of excel writer library?

Comment: ` file.write({**data_dic, 'TXTName': os.path.basename(file_name)}) ` Only can save the last TXT file's name. But I have many files, what should I do for it?

Comment: See also: [previous CSV solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66419141/4985733)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add `file_name` as another entry to be written. As you have constructed a dictionary, a better approach would be to add a new key value pair before writing:

```
data_dic['TXTName'] = os.path.basename(drr)
file.write(data_dic)
```

As your output header is not consistent with the keys in your text files, you need to create a dictionary to map between the two, e.g. `field_mapping`

You were also storing directory names into your list of file? A simpler approach is to just use `glob.glob()` which also can work recursively and also just on `.txt` files if needed.

```
import glob
import xlwt

# {Your header : Key in text file}
field_mapping = {
    'Team ID' : 'Name',
    'Result' : 'Score',
    'Used Time' : 'Used Time',
    'Core Version' : 'Core Version',
    'Software Ver' : 'Software Version',
    'MapName' : 'MapName',
    'AppID' : 'AppID',
    'Key' : 'Key',
    'REG Date' : 'REG Date',
    'Expiry' : 'Expiry',
    'TXTName' : 'TXTName',
}

def getFileData(drr):
    with open(drr) as f_input  :
        return f_input.readlines()

class WFile():
    def __init__(self,head_name):
        super().__init__()
        self.head_name = head_name
        self.index = 0
        self.workbook = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
        self.worksheet = self.workbook.add_sheet('Sheet1')
        self.line = len(self.head_name)

        for i in range(self.line):
            self.worksheet.write(self.index, i, self.head_name[i])

        self.index += 1

    def write(self, d):
        for i, v in enumerate(self.head_name):
            name = d.get(field_mapping[v])
            self.worksheet.write(self.index, i, (name))
        self.index += 1

    def save(self,name):
        self.workbook.save(name)


file_name_path = r"\my file\location\*.txt"    # or just * for all files
excel_header = ['Team ID', 'Result', 'Used Time', 'Software Ver', 'Core Version', 'AppID', 'Key', 'REG Date', 'Expiry','MapName','TXTName']
file = WFile(excel_header)

for file_name in glob.glob(file_name_path, recursive=True):
    file_datas = getFileData(file_name)
    file_datas = file_datas[:7]
    data_list = []

    for data in file_datas:
        for li in data.split(";"):
            data_list.append(li)

    data_dic = {}

    for data in data_list:
        pos = data.find(":")
        ddq = data[:pos].strip()
        data_dic[ddq] = data[pos+1:].strip()

    data_dic['TXTName'] = os.path.basename(file_name)
    file.write(data_dic)

file.save("excel.xls")
```

Giving you an old style output `.xls` file of:

[image: Contents of Excel file]

---

You should consider using the newer `.xlsx` format, with a library such as `openpyxl`.

```
import openpyxl
from itertools import islice
import glob
import os

field_mapping = {
    'Name' : 'Team ID',
    'Score' : 'Result',
    'Used Time' : 'Used Time',
    'Core Version' : 'Core Ver',
    'Software Version' : 'Software Ver',
    'AppID' : 'AppID',
    'Key' : 'Key',
    'REG Date' : 'REG Date',
    'Expiry' : 'Expiry',
    'TXTName' : 'TXTName'
}

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.append(list(field_mapping.values()))     # write a header

for filename in glob.glob('/my folder/*.txt', recursive=True):
    key_values = {}

    with open(filename) as f_input:
        for field in ''.join(islice(f_input, 0, 7)).replace('\n', '').split(';'):
            key, value = map(str.strip, field.split(':', 1))    # only split on the first colon
            key_values[field_mapping.get(key, None)] = value

    key_values['TXTName'] = os.path.basename(filename)
    output_row = [value for key, value in key_values.items() if key]    # Ignore key=None
    ws.append(output_row)

wb.save('excel.xlsx')
```

Comment: Hi Martin. The output only can save the last TXT file's name. But I have many files, what should I do about it?

Comment: I am guessing your problem is with `WFile`, your code works for each filename (try adding `print(drr)` inside your loop, but `WFile` may be overwriting previous entries. You have not included this in your question.

Comment: Hi Martin, I've updated the script to include `WFile` in `wri_file`.